# VBS exit loop where no more track changes exist in word document

Tags: vba, loops, exit, ms-word

I have the following code that builds a string of MS word pages that contain track changes (markup). At the end of the loop I exit where track changes are contained on the last page.

However where there are no track changes on the last page I am stuck in a loop (no pun intended). During the run I get the confirmation box 'do you want to start the the beginning of the document' and it loops

How can I add an 'exit do', so where the last track changes are found (not on the last page) the do statement is exited?

```
    Sub finaltest()
      Dim CurPage As Integer      
      Dim totalPages As Integer
      Dim Pages As String

    'declare variables
      Pages = ""

      'total page count
      ActiveDocument.Repaginate
      totalPages = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

      'get us home
      Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory


      Do
        'find next change
        WordBasic.NextChangeOrComment

        'get current page
        CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Pages = Pages & ", " & CurPage


        '<exit loop if there is no more track changes and not at last page>


      Loop Until CurPage = totalPages
      Pages = Right(Pages, Len(Pages) - 2)
      MsgBox Pages
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear which revision elements you really need to track as far as you use `WordBasic.NextChangeOrComment` instruction.

However, assuming that you need to track revisions but not comments you could insert the code below right after the comment you put to your Sub:

```
'<exit loop if there is no more track changes and not at last page>
With ActiveDocument.Content.Revisions
    If Selection.Range = .Item(.Count).Range Then

        'MsgBox "Last one" - for test only
        Exit Do

    End If
End With
```

If you need to trace comments to you need to create similar solution as for revision items (`Comments collection` doesn't include `Revisions collection` and vice-versa).